# dev_appserver wont use my index.yaml python3.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-3.7, app-engine-ndb

I'm in the process of upgrading a python2.7 gae std app to python3.7. 
Everything is great except my indices just wont work.

I have a simple looking index.yaml file:

```
indexes:

- kind: Response
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

And when I run certain commands then I get this

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Response
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: __key__
    direction: desc
```

The command I'm using to run dev_appserver is: `dev_appserver.py --application=my_project_id app.yaml`. 
My index.yaml file lives in the same directory as my app.yaml file.

Nothing else is running. The application itself is a Flask api, the error is coming up when I `curl` one of the endpoints.

**What I've tried**

After poking around docs and SO for a bit it seems like I might need to run the datastore emulator locally. So made sure that my gcloud components were up to date then:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init

# which gave me:

export DATASTORE_DATASET=firestore-datastore-280307
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8608
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=::1:8608/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://::1:8608
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=firestore-datastore-280307

# then

gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project=my_project_id

# which gave me 

stuff...

[datastore] API endpoint: http://::1:8679
[datastore] If you are using a library that supports the DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:
[datastore] 
[datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8679
[datastore] 
[datastore] Dev App Server is now running.
```

So by combining these outputs it looks like my environment should be like:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=my_project_id
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8679
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=::1:8679/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://::1:8679
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my_project_id
```

Cool. So I leave the emulator running and try to get my dev_appserver to connect to it:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET=my_project_id
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=::1:8679
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=::1:8679/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://::1:8679
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my_project_id
dev_appserver.py --application=my_project_id app.yaml
```

It starts up but when I `curl` my endpoint I get the same index error.

So then I kill dev_appserver and try it like this:

```
# same env vars as before
dev_appserver.py --support_datastore_emulator=true --application=my_project_id app.yaml
```

Then I get a new error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot use the Cloud Datastore Emulator because the packaged grpcio is incompatible to this system. Please install grpcio using pip
```

I pip installed grpcio in a python2.7 env to get over that error. Now it looks like everything is running. But I'm still getting the missing index error.

And another strange thing: If I go to `http://localhost:8000` and try navigating to anythin to do with datastores then I get errors like:

`ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Cloud Datastore Emulator on ::1:{THE_PORT}`

Which is very weird.

I'm considering going back to 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go back to 2.7!  If you have this problem in production, go to your developer console and check your indexes: https://console.cloud.google.com/.....
See if they are still building. It does take some time for the indexes to build.

If this only happens in development:

`dev_appserver` is buggy in Windows.  I couldn't tell if you in on Windows or not.  I had problems using dev_appserver in a virtual environment even on Mac when porting an app to Python 3.7.

You state you are using Flask.  Try using the Flask server in development instead of dev_appserver.  That is what worked for me. There is good documentation on this.  You will start it with something like:

```
cd /Users/myname/venv37
source ./bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=/Users/myname/path_to_app
FLASK_ENV=development flask run --port 5000
```

### edit:

`ndb` is not compatible with python 3.7.  They have developed a new service Google Cloud NDB which makes the old ndb data usable:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/migrating-to-cloud-ndb

New apps should use Cloud Datastore or Firestore.  But legacy `ndb` apps can migrate to Google Cloud NDB.

Comment: You got me to the right solution... basically the datastore emulater is either broken or not compatable with ndb on py3.7. So I had to use an actual cloud based datastore to be able to develop. If you want to you can edit your answer to say that and then I'll accept it